# Right click position in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu, mouseevent, right-click

I create my own context menu inside a Canvas when the user right click, but I need to know the (x,y) coordinates in the stage.

I'm trying `mouseX` and `mouseY`, but is not working as I expected, returning coordinates of the last click (even inside a menu option), not where I clicked to show the context menu.

**Is there any way to get mouse position from right click in Flex?**

Answer (score 1):

Flash prevents you from accessing the right click event.

However, you can use some javascript hacking to work around this issue. You will find several example on the web, and i successfully used [this one](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/right-click-and-custom-context-menu-in-flash-flex/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the context menu is already created. I just need the coordinates for using them as a parameter into the handler function of one option. I'm going to read the link provided anyways :)

Comment: [Read the link before] Oh i tought you would reimplement it... If you are happy with flash native menu and you just want to get the right click event's coordinates, I think there is no pure flex way to do it. However, you can use the script behind my link and remove the "kill event" part, so you have the native context menu, and in the callback called by the javascript code, you store the coordinates of the last right click on a global variable, making it accessible when the option is activated. it's kinda dirty, but i think it's the only way.

Comment: I recently read your link carefully, but it doesn't solve my problem. Anyways, thanks for the tip (directly to my bookmarks).